# how to create a custom finder and form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to CakePHP3 and trying to create a form to add new items in Database

I am creating a online food ordering website my struture is like

```
Categories ( has many)
  |_ Products 
  |_ Sizes
  |_ Toppings
```

For example in Categories `Pizza` may have many sizes like `small`, `large`, `party`

and also have many `toppings`. Each topping will cost extra depending on the size ordered. for example for samll pizza it costs 0.5$, for large 1$ etc

Now if I want to create Topping for a Category, I have a name field and as many price fields as Category's sizes

e.g Pizza has 3 Sizes the add Topping `.ctp` should display a name field and
3 price field one for each size.

I have created a table named `Toppings_Prices`
which have these fields `topping_id, size_id, price` now my question is how I can write a finder which delivers the available sizes for a category
from ToppingsController's add/edit method.

And how shouldI name the form fields for prices fields so that I can save the prices in topping_prices table

Answer (score 0):

> how I can write a finder which delivers the available sizes for a
>   category

assuming `$category_id` contains the id of the category of the product you are editing.

```
$this->loadModel('Sizes');
$sizes = $this->Sizes->find('list')
    ->where(['category_id' => $category_id]);
```

> And how shouldI name the form fields for prices fields so that I can
>   save the prices in topping_prices table

```
toppings_prices.0.size_id
toppings_prices.0.price

toppings_prices.1.size_id
toppings_prices.1.price
```

and so on depending on how many prices you want to add to the topping at the same time. See the [**manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) for reference